# Flag column or foreign key?

Tags: sql, ddl

I have ENTERPRISES and DOMAINS table.  The property of each enterprise is that it should have a single primary domain, but it can have more than one domain.  I have come up with this table structure

```
+---------------------------------------+
| ENTERPRISES                           |
+----+--------------+-------------------+
| ID | Name         | Primary Domain ID |
+----+--------------+-------------------+
| 1  | Enterprise A | 2                 |
| 2  | Enterprise B | 4                 |
+----+--------------+-------------------+

+---------------------------------------+
| DOMAINS                               |
+----+------------------+---------------+
| ID | Domain Name      | Enterprise ID |
+----+------------------+---------------+
| 1  | ent-a.com        | 1             |
| 2  | enterprise-a.com | 1             |
| 3  | ent-b.com        | 2             |
| 4  | enterprise-b.com | 2             |
+----+------------------+---------------+
```

My co-worker suggested this alternative structure:

```
+-------------------+
| ENTERPRISES       |
+----+--------------+
| ID | Name         |
+----+--------------+
| 1  | Enterprise A |
| 2  | Enterprise B |
+----+--------------+

+----------------------------------------------------+
| DOMAINS                                            |
+----+------------------+---------------+------------+
| ID | Domain Name      | Enterprise ID | Is Primary |
+----+------------------+---------------+------------+
| 1  | ent-a.com        | 1             | False      |
| 2  | enterprise-a.com | 1             | True       |
| 3  | ent-b.com        | 2             | False      |
| 4  | enterprise-b.com | 2             | True       |
+----+------------------+---------------+------------+
```

My question is, which one is more efficient/correct?

Also, in the first example should I use ID for primary domain column or a string value, so ENTERPRISES table does not have a circular dependency on DOMAINS table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Circular *references* are OK. Circular *dependencies* are not. As long as `Primary Domain ID` is nullable, then you're fine. Otherwise you'll have a chicken-or-the-egg scenario, being unable to create a `Domain` without an `Enterprise`, but also unable to create an `Enterprise` without a `Primary Domain ID`.

**I would choose the former (your proposed solution)**, because you're defining a one-to-one relationship. While the `Enterprise->Domain` relationship is one-to-many, the `Enterprise->Primary Domain` relationship is one-to-one.

Answer (score 3):

Both are *correct*. But go for the FK.

**The one you suggest has less sparse data**, while in the second example you may have 100 domains belonging to the same company, all with `IsPrimary` set to `False` and just one domain set to `True`.

Also, **it's easier to enforce exactly one primary domain in the first scenario**, while in the second you'll have to write a trigger or a check in your code to see that there is one, and only one, primary domain at all times.

Again, stick to the FK.

Answer (score 1):

In the first model you say an Enterprise should have a single primary domain. Expand that a moment and say it will have a single primary domain. At this point you'd be inclined to mark that column as not nullable.

The problem then is you won't be able to insert data since you've created a circular depedancy. You can't insert an enterprise without a domain and you can't insert a domain without an enterprise.

I prefer the first model as it is cleaner and more explicit. Your model enforces that there is a single primary domain where there is nothing in the second model so you'd be forced to enforce this rule using some other mechanism.